# Yii2 - syntax error - while loading the index page

Tags: parsing, syntax, yii2-advanced-app

I am Getting a syntax error, while installing yeesoft/yii2-yee-core through composer.

> ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']' in C:\new\htdocs\mysite.com\common\config\main.php on line 19

Code Snippet:
[code snippet part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUTrX.gif) and 
[code snippet part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaXGY.gif)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should never post a screenshot of your code. please see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/).

Comment: Thank you. I will take care of this next time, @SouravGhosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was a syntax error, with a bracket at a location missing.

If you have any other points to add, please do.

Answer (score 1):

On line 19 you have:

```
'rules' => array[
```

This is syntactically incorrect. You should change this to:

```
'rules' => [
```

Since you typically define an array in either one of two ways:

```
$array = ['value_one', 'value_two'];
$another_array = array('value_one', 'value_two');
```

See [Array Syntax in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: bracket at other location was missing.